# How to change the order of argument if they're same type?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, methods, parameters, ide

How to change the order of argument if they're same type in vscode?

I'm writing java, and I just have a big problem right now

example: I have a method

```
void employee(int age, int id) {
    ...
}
```

But one day, I thought that it's better if the id is in front of age:

```
void employee(int id, int age) {
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, when I realized that, I had already use it hundred or even thousand time, do vscode have support with change order of it?

Comment: how would you do it if they where of different type: the same

Comment: @rioV8 If different, I also cannot do anything; but at least, I can use method overloading

Comment: you could have a look at [Astra](https://github.com/alfasoftware/astra), a codemod tool for Java, I suggest you add some checks inside the employee method to validate the arguments, hopefully you don't have id's larger then 100, it is a bad design to have age as argument, it will change tomorrow. It is a calculated property of an object

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use function overloading.

```
void employee(int age, int id) {
    ...
}
```

```
void newEmployee(int id, int age) {
    employee(age,id);
}
```